# spinning wheel start and stop async

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using the loader from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_loader, created a div

```
<div class="row">       
      <div class="loader" id="load1"></div>
</div>
---
--
---
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <legend>Start Running</legend>
  <button type="button" id="btn1" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Start</button>

</div>
```

The basic idea is to make this start spinning after I start uploading a document i.e. click on the button (btn1) and stop when the output is printed on the screen.  The upload/output is working, but I am having hard time to integrate this loader with the start of file upload and end when the output is ready.  Looked at https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/166 and tried to implement but it didn't change the spin behavior

Comment: @PA.  Thanks for the comment.  The code is long.  So, I thought that it would be easier to show the context.  The exact problem is that I have a spinning wheel that is running forever.  I wanted to control it i.e. to start spinning only when the button to run a model is clicked and finish once the output is loaded in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to show a loading image when request to server has been sent and make image disappear when response received.

If that's what you want, just make the image appear when event triggered, and when request loaded make it disappear.

would look something like this:

```
submit_button.addEventListener('click',function(){
    var result = document.querySeletor('#result');
    result.innerHTML = 'loading image';
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onload = function(){
            result.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    request.open(method,path,true);
    request.send();
});
```